# JavaScript: How to get the center of a pie slice?

Tags: javascript, math, canvas, graph

Hi I am trying to create a simple pie chart using the HTML canvas element.
I found a nice tutorial on the web and starting to learn how it is done.

Now I want to add some text and I need to know how to find the center of each slice in the pie where the text can be added.

Here is the loop code:

```
    for ( i = 0; i < t.data.length; i++ )
    {
        label = t.data[i].label;
        value = t.data[i].value;
        color = t.data[i].color;

        ctx.lineWidth = t.strokeLineWidth;
        ctx.strokeStyle = "#FFFFFF";
        ctx.fillStyle = color;

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo( centerX, centerY );
        ctx.arc( centerX, centerY, radius, lastEnd, lastEnd + ( Math.PI * 2 * ( value / total ) ), false );
        ctx.lineTo( centerX, centerY );
        ctx.fill();
        ctx.stroke();

        lastEnd += Math.PI * 2 * ( value / total );
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply treat the slices as triangles, i.e. ignore the arc.

There are a bunch of different ways to define "the center". Have a look [at the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle#Points.2C_lines.2C_and_circles_associated_with_a_triangle) on how to do this. You'll probably want the intersection of the angle bisectors, which is called the **incenter**. This is the center of the inscribed circle, and it gives the most space for text.

The coordinates of the incenter is calculated as follows:

Let (x<sub>a</sub>,y<sub>a</sub>), (x<sub>b</sub>,y<sub>b</sub>), and (x<sub>c</sub>,y<sub>c</sub>) be the coordinates of the three corners of the triangle, and let a, b, and c be the lengths of the opposing sides. I.e., a = ||(x<sub>b</sub>,y<sub>b</sub>)-(x<sub>c</sub>,y<sub>c</sub>)||, etc. Finally, let P=a+b+c. Then the center is

((a x<sub>a</sub> + b x<sub>b</sub> + c x<sub>c</sub>)/P, (a y<sub>a</sub> + b y<sub>b</sub> + c y<sub>c</sub>)/P).

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

The math is more complicated than I can do quickly.  You might try the rgraph library. 
http://www.rgraph.net/docs/pie.html

Comment: RGraph actually has some very useful trigonometry functions that you can make use of: RGraph.getAngleByXY(cx, cy, x, y) RGraph.getHypLength(x1, y1, x2, y2) RGraph.getRadiusEndPoint(cx,cy,angle,radius) (this one could be very useful to you) . Remember that angles are measured in radians. If you're going to use them though you'll have to massage them a little to take them out of the RGraph common core file.